# Add a class to a different class?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add a class to `bookmark_edit` when I click the `bookmark_icons` class. How can I do it with the jQuery?

```
<div class="bookmark_outer">
   <div class="bookmark_txt">
       <h4 id="bookmark_id">Bookmark 1</h4><a href="#" class="bokmarksave"> <img src="icheck-icon.png" class="bookmark_edit"> </a>
      <p> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and </p>
       <p class="page_num">Page 3 </p>
   </div>
   <div class="bookmark_icon"> 
      <a href="#"><img src="edit.png" class="bookmark_icons"></a> 
      <a href="#" class="Bkhide"><img src="idelete.png" class="bookmark_icons"> </a>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `jquary` => `jQuery`

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/click & http://api.jquery.com/addClass

Comment: Also, please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), and more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: jquary > jquery

Comment: If you don't know how to do such simple thing as bind a click handler and add a class, I would recommend that you do some tutorials as this is very basic stuff,  I would also add a separate class to identify your edit button otherwise you'll be binding your edit function to your delete icon too

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".bookmark_edit").unbind("click").bind("click", function(event) {
    $(event.target).addClass("my_class");
}
```

Comment: you missed the part where you should bind this in a click event on bookmark_icon